# How to show data from two model with sum column eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

i have two table with the following details:

**Ecourse table**

- id
- slug
- title
- logo
- description
- price
- status

**Traffics table**

- id
- ecourse_id
- date
- amount
- type_traffic

I want to display ecourse data with the amount of traffic per day using eloquent laravel. What's the solution?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide create table structures, sample data and expected result. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
$ecourses = Ecourse::with(['traffics' => function($q){
    $q->groupBy('date')
      ->selectRaw('sum(amount) as sum, date');
}])->get();
```

Keep me posted in the comments below. Cheers!